In a Jupyter Notebook open in VS Code, how can I quickly navigate to the currently running cell?
As per title, this feels like a useful feature but haven't been able to find a setting / extension that offers this capability.

Just figured it out - you can use the "Go To" button in the top toolbar in vscode (pic below). You'll need the jupyter extension installed.


Glad to know your problem has been solved! See Can I answer my own question?  Just a reminder :)
